# "MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo" while running atlas-cli pi command

Tags: maven, jira, pom.xml, jira-plugin, mojo

I try to compile my custom jira plugin by running atlas-cli pi command. 
It worked when I used repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/. Now it changed to http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1081192444

This is the text of error:

```
[ERROR] Unable to complete running command: pi
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unab
le to execute mojo
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.run(ExecuteGoalComma
nd.java:112)
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.commands.ExecuteGoalCommand.run(ExecuteGoalComma
nd.java:107)
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.CliShell.interpretCommand(CliShell.java:48)
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.CliShell.run(CliShell.java:29)
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.AbstractCliMojo.displayShell(AbstractCliMojo.jav
a:170)
        at org.twdata.maven.cli.AbstractCliMojo.access$000(AbstractCliMojo.java:
22)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectExc
eption: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle
(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:126)
        at com.atlassian.maven.plugins.pdk.InstallPluginMojo$BasicAuthFilter.han
dle(InstallPluginMojo.java:425)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:365)
```

My version:

```
ATLAS Version:    4.2.20
ATLAS Home:       C:\atlassian-plugin-sdk
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven
--------
Executing: "C:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven\bin\mvn.bat" --version -gs C:\a
tlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 2.1.0 (r755702; 2009-03-18 22:10:27+0300)
Java version: 1.6.0_38
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

I've just found that it could be wrong version in pom.xml.
But when I wrote another version in pom.xml I got error:

```
ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
```

Please, can anyone help?

Repository in my settings.xml:

```
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>maven-plugin-repo</id>
                    <url>hhttp://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1081192444</url>
                </pluginRepository>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>xproduct-admin-ui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>xproduct-admin-ui-plugin</name>
    <description>This plugin has an admin UI that can be used in any Atlassian product.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.templaterenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-template-renderer-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4-m1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-amps-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.20</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.atlassian.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-jira-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [4.2.10,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                compress-resources
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <refapp.version>4.2.4</refapp.version>
    </properties>
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>https-atlassian</id>
      <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an acient version of Maven? Apart from that the repository entry which contains `search.maven.org` is simply wrong! You don't need to add Maven Central cause it's default.

Comment: Thisi is really old project, now I should compile it. 
I've updated Maven but error still the same 
ATLAS Version:    5.0.13
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T21:37:5
2+04:00)
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Comment: What exact command are you using to invoke atlas-cli? Also, what is the exact URL you use to access the JIRA instance you are trying to upload it to? You would want to use `atlas-cli --context-path "" -p 8080` if you are, for example, trying to upload to a JIRA instance at http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.2.20 of the Atlassian Plugin SDK is only compatible with Maven 2.1.0 - so don't update Maven to 3.2.1.  If you do update Maven, you'll need to update the Atlassian Plugin SDK to version 5.x as well.

As for your settings.xml, try removing it entirely. The Atlassian Plugin SDK comes bundled with a pre-configured settings.xml which has all the required configuration specified for you (it's in `C:\a
tlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven\conf\settings.xml`). If you need a custom settings.xml for other Maven development purposes, you will need to reconcile your settings with the ones shipped with the SDK and make sure you're not overriding anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Repository in my settings.xml:

```
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>maven-plugin-repo</id>
                <url>hhttp://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1081192444</url> 
            </pluginRepository>
```

You have a mistake hhttp://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1081192444, it should be http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1081192444